# Using XSLT include to change namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, import, namespaces, include

The XML documents I'm transforming are identical in structure but have been given different namespaces depending on their category of data (tag name and actual namespace).  I wanted to have one XSLT for all of them by using wildcards but ran into the problem that I couldn't wildcard out a tag since I needed it for specificity.

I'm trying to create a XSLT wrapper for each category that includes the data category's namespace and then have a single file with all the xslt templates in it.  I have zero control over the source xml.  What I seem to be seeing is that the included xml requires redefinition of all the namespaces which completely defeats what I'm trying to do.  I'm using the Saxon engine.

Comment: How many different namespaces do you have to handle?

Comment: Can you show us samples of the input and XSLT you have so far together with the output you want? You also might want to tell us exactly which version of Saxon you use as XSLT 3.0 in the latest 9.6 with static variables and shadow attributes might allow new ways to parameterize namespace handling.

Comment: #1
<bca:tca_bcr ... xmlns:bca="bca/2.6" ...xmlns:bca_shared="bca/shared/2.6"...>
...
    <bca:person>
      .... 
       <bca_shared:er_method_text>...</bca_shared:er_method_text>
#2
<lih:tca_bcr ... xmlns:lih="lih/2.6" ...xmlns:bca_shared="lih/shared/2.6"...>
...
    <lih:person>
      .... 
       <lih_shared:er_method_text>...</lih_shared:er_method_text>
so to use the same xpath for both I used wildcard: 
<xsl:value-of select="/*:tca_bcr/*:person/*:er_detection_method_text"/>

Comment: Which worked until I found something that looked like this:
 <follow_up_v2.1:follow_up version="2.1" sequence="1">
 <follow_up_v4.0:follow_up version="4.0" sequence="1">
Where the namespace declarations were 
xmlns:follow_up_v2.1="bca/followup/2.6/2.1"
Which includes that "bca" that I'm trying to get away from.  I can't put 
<xsl:value-of select="/*:tca_bcr/*:person/*:follow_up"/> since I need to know which one I'm getting back.  As I'm writing this it occurs to me that maybe I could put a conditional on what I get back.

Comment: @dupdup, please edit your question and insert the code samples there with proper formatting and markup.

Comment: "*I couldn't wildcard out a tag since I needed it for specificity.*"  What exactly does  "*needed it for specificity*" mean?